# Django: use the forloop value from a parent template

Tags: django, django-templates

Can I get the forloop value out of a parent template forloop? I.e.:

```
parent.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for i in nnn %}
        {% include child.html %}
    {% endfor %}
{% end block %}

child.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ forloop.counter from parent.html }}
{% endblock %}

def ViewParent(request):
    return render_to_response('parent.html', {}, context_instance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` template tag supports the passage of arguments using the [`with` keyword](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

parent.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for i in nnn %}
        {% include child.html with loop_counter=forloop.counter %}
    {% endfor %}
{% end block %}
```

child.html:

```
{{ loop_counter }}
```

Note that you probably don't actually mean to extend the child template from the same base template as the parent, so I have omitted that in this example.

Comment: I hope you mean `{% ... with loop_counter=i %}`. I understand your comment about extending `base.html`, but I have a page with elements which might or might not be included. So what you are looking at is my way of trying to abstract the construction of the rendered html. So there could have been an `{% if boo %} {% include element.html %} {% endif %}` before the `parent.html` forloop.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean `=1`.  I updated with `loop_counter=forloop.counter` to make consistent with your example.